# Execute CURL command from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, curl

Hi I need to integrate my rails 3.2 application with pivotaltracker to CRUD projects and stories. In their documentation [pivotal tracker api link](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api#Getting_Started) they provided some commands to create, ready story using CURL. I want to know how to use those commands in rails.

Example command to create story:

```
export TOKEN='your Pivotal Tracker API token'
export PROJECT_ID=99
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-TrackerToken: $TOKEN" -d '{"current_state":"started","name":"Exhaust ports are ray shielded","estimate":1}' "https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/projects/$PROJECT_ID/stories"
```

how can i achieve this in rails?

Answer (score 1):

Net::HTTP ruby module can do the same things.
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

But if you want execute shell commad like curl try Kernel#system
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this instead of using direct `curl` command.

```
$ gem install curb
```

Then you can you

```
Curl::Easy.perform("http://www.google.co.uk") do |curl| 
 curl.headers["User-Agent"] = "myapp-0.0"
 curl.verbose = true
end
```

See the [documentation](http://taf2.github.io/curb/) and [Github](https://github.com/taf2/curb)